# Can you populate a ListBox with data entered within a ComboBox in VB?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, combobox, listbox, populate

I have a program that has a number of fields that the user can input data into, and also a number of ComboBoxes that the user can select data from.

My question is is it possible to use this selected data to populate a ListBox, or multiple ListBoxes (One for each field).

I currently have this code that populates the ComboBoxes:

```
    Private Sub BusinessSalesPage_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.ComboBox1.Items.AddRange(New String() {"0", "1-2", "3-9", "10-19", "20-49", "50-99", "100+"})
    Me.ComboBox2.Items.AddRange(New String() {"0", "0-1", "2-4", "5+"})
    Me.ComboBox3.Items.AddRange(New String() {"<£1k", "£1k-£5k", "£5k-£10k", "£10k-£29k"})
    Me.ComboBox4.Items.AddRange(New String() {"1-10", "10-20", "20-50"})
    Me.ComboBox5.Items.AddRange(New String() {"<£50k", "£50k-£100k", "£100k-£250k"})
    Me.ComboBox6.Items.AddRange(New String() {"Limited", "Partnership", "PLC"})
    Me.ComboBox7.Items.AddRange(New String() {"Established more than 5 years", "Established in 2007", "Established in 2008", "Established in 2009"})
    Me.ComboBox8.Items.AddRange(New String() {"CEO", "Deputy Head", "Manager", "Other"})
    Me.ComboBox9.Items.AddRange(New String() {"Marketing", "Energy Provider", "Retail", "IT"})
    Me.ComboBox10.Items.AddRange(New String() {"Post Code", "Account Number", "Phone Number", "Business Name"})
End Sub
```

Yes I am new to VB, thanks in advance.

It might be worth noting that I am using TabPages to navigate through the form.

Edit:

I just want to take user input from one textBox and display it into a ListBox
Here is what I have so far:

```
    Dim postcode As String = String.Empty

    postcode = TextBox16.Text

    If postcode = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a postcode")
    Else

    End If
```

Not sure what needs to go into ElseIf to make the inout go into ListBox1

Comment: It's not very clear what is getting displayed in the ListBox or why, since the value is already displayed in the ComboBox.  It sounds a little bit like you are implementing a PropertyGrid type display.  Also, "1-10", "10-20" overlap on the 10 value.  Guessing you meant "11-20" and "21-50".

Comment: For now don't worry about the content. I quickly chucked that in there to get some output. I don't know if it is possible to do what I want. The population should happen onClick.

Comment: You mean on "SelectedIndexChanged" of the ComboBox?  It's stll not clear though: are all of these combo box values getting displayed in a ListBox?  You mentioned multiple ListBoxes.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. Instead, can I take information entered into a TextBox and populate it into a ListBox. The ListBoxes are not yet generated. But is it possible? I would like this to happen onClick. For example data entered into a Company name TextBox could populate a ListBox called Company name?

Comment: @LarsTech I have edited the post. Think this is a simpler solution.

Comment: Just use `ListBox1.Items.Add(postcode)`.

Comment: Something very simple as I thought... Thanks again for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need below

```
        listbox1.Items.Add(postcode)
```